# Apposition, commas and clause/phrase definition

Tags: grammaticality

I am looking at some appositives with proper nouns and wanted to know how they are analysed. The sentence is:
"My brother, named John, is happy."

I am confused with the verb "named". Does it make the "named John" a separate clause? eg.

My brother, // named John, // is happy.

I know the relative clause "My brother, // who is named John // is happy." has a slightly different meaning. I want to know how the verbs before proper nouns are analysed (named, called, labelled etc.)

Thanks for your time

Comment: I don't see any difference in meaning between *who is named John* and *named John*. In the nonrestrictive clause, *who is* is assumed to exist. You could also remove *named* altogether, leaving it as only *John* between the pair of commas. Also, the information between the comma pairs could just as easily be *dressed in blue* or *stumbling home*, so it's not clear what the specific issue is with *named*, as opposed to any other verb or adjective.

Comment: @JasonBassford it is not a case of ellipsis. "My John-named brother" wouldn't be.

Comment: At a very basic level of understanding ylu have a referential noun, "my brother" and two predicats, "is named John", "is happy". "John" could be seen as a syntagmatic vocative (by some analysts) and *named* as an adverb of the vocative. I'm not sure what kind of adverb that would be.

Comment: To be more natural, you could say 'My brother, John, is happy.' It's obvious that John is his name.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @marcellothearcane the sentence without the "named" is a non-restrictive appositive and has a different meaning. I also am not quite sure if  'named John' in 'My brother named John is fun' is an embedded clause or adjectival phrase. I'm leaning toward embedded clause.